# Why doen't width with percentage work in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my code and it works well.

```css
.c-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.c-plate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 96px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-table">
   <div class="c-plate red"></div>
   <div class="c-plate blue"></div>
   <div class="c-plate yellow"></div>
</div>
```

I changed `width` of `.c-plate` like this:

```css
.c-plate {
  width: 50%;
  height: 96px;
}
```

```css
.c-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.c-plate {
  width: 50%;
  height: 96px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-table">
   <div class="c-plate red"></div>
   <div class="c-plate blue"></div>
   <div class="c-plate yellow"></div>
</div>
```

I expected that the width of each div with `c-plate` class becomes 50% of the `c-table` width.

However, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Your `.c-table` does not have a width?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? How do you exactly want it to be? I have tested it and it works fine with all of the children occupying 50% of the width of the screen. Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/geekyquentin/pen/MWQVEaz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like expected. the with of the child (c-plate) is relative to the width from the parent (c-table).

It means if you want change the relative width from the c-plate elements you must set the width on c-table.

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

.c-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  width: 50%;
  background: gray;
}

.c-plate {
  width: 50%;
  height: 96px;
}

.red {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
}

.blue {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
}

.yellow {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="c-table">
   <div class="c-plate red"></div>
   <div class="c-plate blue"></div>
   <div class="c-plate yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Geeky Quentin, it is the intended behaviour.

You set `.c-plate` to have `50%` `width`. Elements with `.c-plate` will look for its parent to take `50%` of. Since your `.c-table` does not have a width property set, it just becomes `50%` of `body`.

You can set the width of `.c-table` to make `.c-plate`s inherit from that width. However, it will still be `50%` and since there are 3 `.c-plate`s, it will be `150%` total and wrap around to the next line since `flex-wrap` is `wrap`.

```css
.c-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  width: 500px;
}

.c-plate {
  width: 50%;
  height: 96px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-table">
   <div class="c-plate red"></div>
   <div class="c-plate blue"></div>
   <div class="c-plate yellow"></div>
</div>
```

If this is not the desired outcome, you will have to be more specific what you want.

Do you want to have something like this?

```css
.c-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  width: 500px;
}

.c-plate {
  width: 33%;
  height: 96px;
}

.red {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
}

.blue {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
}

.yellow {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="c-table">
   <div class="c-plate red"></div>
   <div class="c-plate blue"></div>
   <div class="c-plate yellow"></div>
</div>
```